# Displaying 0 when using system("") command in c++

Tags: c++, windows

I am fairly new to C++ and I am making a basic login system... Although when I cout something like "incorrect password" and change the colour of the text using system("color 4") to red, it displays a zero before it. Has anyone had this problem before and if so, how did you resolve it. Thanks =)

```
cout << endl << system("color 4") << "Incorrect Password";
```

Comment: [When you ask a question, please show a complete example that exhibits the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As it is, have you considered just sending the control characters from within your program, rather than using `system`?

Comment: First show a complete example to understand better

Comment: `color 4` is not a valid command for my shell... I assume you are using Windows, so please edit question and add the Windows tag.

Comment: I have considered doing that although it seems more complicated compared to the system command. If there isn't a solution I guess I'll have to.

Comment: You are outputting the return value of `system()`, hence the `0` is displayed. Just change to `cout << endl; system("color 4"); cout << "Incorrect Password";`.

Comment: The code he posted is an example of the problem occurring. Is it necessary to include the `main` function wrapping it?

Comment: @Dennis: That is what "[...] complete and verifiable example" means. The idea is that the OP adds whatever is needed to copy & paste & compile & reproduce, not each of the dozens of people trying to answer the question individually. This one was easy to answer without that information, but the OP cannot know that.

Comment: @DevSolar - Good point. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are *printing* the *return code* of [`system()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system), which is an implementation-defined value, but for most platforms is zero on successful completion of the command.

The code does exactly what you told it to do. ;-)

You *could* execute the `system()` call *before* the `cout` line. (If that works for you.)

Generally speaking, `system()` should be avoided. It's usually a crutch for "I don't know how to do this properly", it's platform-dependent, and most beginners fail to check the return value properly (which is "implementation-defined" to boot), making the program prone to silent failures of whatever the program wants to (attempt to) call.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll avoid system() in the future.

Comment: @billy606: Generic debugging advice: In 99.999% of all cases, the code does *exactly* what you told it to. The question is (virtually) never "why does it do that?", but "where have I accidentially told it to do that?". Together with "read the documentation for the functions you are using", that will solve the majority of beginner problems. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The `system` function executes a command in the console and returns the status code. You do not want to output the status code result, so don't call `system` in your output stream

```
cout << endl;
system("color 4");
cout << "Incorrect Password";
```

Answer (score 0):

The [system()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system) function returns an int, whose value is implementation defined. It appears to be 0 in your case, this is why that value gets printed. If you don't want that, just don't print it:

```
std::system("color 4");
std::cout << "Incorrect Password\n";
```